# Session variable for login not passing to redirected page on first attempt

Tags: php, session, authentication

hi I have a login system for my admin section that i have a problem with, the problem is that the first time the user attempts to login, the $_SESSION isn't passed to the target page,
on the second attempt it works fine, this is what is called on the login page

```
$membership = new Membership();
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['pwd'])) {
$response = $membership->validate_User($_POST['username'], $_POST['pwd']);
```

}

in the class memebership

```
function validate_user($un, $pwd) {

    $ensure_credentials =  $this->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd);

    if($ensure_credentials) {
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
        $_SESSION['id'] = $ensure_credentials;

        header("location: ambassadorUpdate.php");
        die;
    } else return "Please enter a correct username and password";

}
```

i've checked the code when i don't then send to ambassadorUpdate and the SESSION is set however if i use the header to redirect to page then the first time the SESSION is not 
there is a session_start on both pages,

the code runs fine when all the pages where in the same folder, however i am getting this problem when i have organised them in a separate admin folder however all of the files are included correctly,

any ideas greatly appreciated many thanks

Comment: This code couldn't possibly work - you're doing an echo before the header() call, meaning that output has occured, and php will simply spit out the "headers already sent" warning.

Comment: just put echo in their to check the first part of the code where header wasn't receiving session forget to take it off here will take it out

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify:

```
$membership = new Membership();
if($_POST && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['pwd'])) {
$response = $membership->validate_User($_POST['username'], $_POST['pwd']);
}

if ($response == true){
    header("location: ambassadorUpdate.php");
} else echo "Please enter a correct username and password";
```

in the class memebership

```
function validate_user($un, $pwd) {

    $ensure_credentials =  $this->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd);

    if($ensure_credentials) {
        echo 'workied';
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
        $_SESSION['id'] = $ensure_credentials;
        echo $_SESSION['status'] . $_SESSION['id'];
        return = true;
    } else return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks but no joy i'm afraid, SESSION returns to the login page, can echo $_SESSION['status'] . $_SESSION['id']; if i want to on it, but if instead try to redirect to new page the SESSION is lost on first attempt, (still works second time)

Answer (score 0):

I can't create an comment, so i write an answer. 
Have you check `session_start() in ambassadorUpdate.php`. Does your browser accept cookies? 
If not, it is usefull to use `"location: ambassadorUpdate.php".?SID` or you can use `session_name()=session_id()` instead  of SID

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, browser accepts and yes like i said i'm using session_start the code works on the second attempt it also works if the pages are in the same folder

Comment: Some other question: Same effect in other browser? I can remember for a problem like this. A Firefox plugin was the problem.